# How to get rid of this UI "feature"/bug(without rebooting)?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gui, unity-dash

Please look at this strange border - I have Firefox opened, as usual, but after pressing some keys a strange border appeared(can be seen between the dash icon and the google logo, overlapping the Firefox window) :

[image: Strange border]   **highlighted ->**   [image: highlighted]

Note that this border overlaps *everything*, not only the firefox window, bot also the background wallpaper etc. and can become quite annoying.

This border stretches over the entire screen, but I didn't want to bother you with a 1900x1200 screenshot...

What can I do to "fix" this, ie remove that ugly thing(ideally without rebooting or logging off) ?

*Plus : Is this a bug or a feature ?*

My version is 16.04.

Thanks in advance for your time and possible help.

EDIT : Rebooting fixes this. Question still persists.

Comment: Does this happen with other application windows or just that browser?

Comment: @thomasrutter with everything, it's a constant overlay. Disappeared after rebooting, but I'm curious to know the exact cause.